# How do I prove this relation is in the `3FN`?

Tags: database-design, normalization

Consider the relation `R(A,B,C,D,E)` and the set of functional dependencies `F={A->D,D->C,BC->AE}`

I need to prove this relation is in the `3FN`, however I don't think it is; in fact, I don't even think it is in the `2FN`.

My reasoning is the following:

I think my candidate key is `AB`, as `AB->A,B`, through the reflective property. Because it determines `A`, it also determines `D` and `C`, by transitivity. By pseudo transitivity `AB->AE`, so `AB` also determines `E`; I can't find any subset of `AB` that also determines every other non key attribute, so I think `AB` is a candidate key.

Because `AB` is the candidate key, the relation is in the `3FN` if it's in the `2FN` and to be in the `2FN`, for every non key attribute `X`, `AB->X` is elementary, i.e., there can't be a subset of `AB` that also determines `X`; this condition already fails in `AB->D`, as `A->D`.

Even if it was in the `2FN`, it can't also be in the `3FN`, as there can't be any non key attribute that depends on another non key attribute, but there cleary are, e.g., `D->C`.

Am I doing anything wrong, as I can't see how this relation is in the `3FN`, but I have to prove it is so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A relation is in third normal form when for all the FDs `X -> Y` of a cover `F` of the dependencies of the relation we have that either `X` is a superkey, or `Y` is prime. So we can prove that `R` is in 3NF if we can show that this condition is true for all the dependencies of `F`.

The relation has three candidate keys (you can easily see that the closure of each of them contains all the attributes of the relation):

```
AB
BC
BD
```

So the only non-prime attribute is `E`. So, `BC->AE` has a determinant which is a superkey, while `A->D` and `D->C` have a determinate which is a prime attribute.

So all the dependencies satisfy the condition and the relation is in 3NF.

Comment: Actually producing all the candidate keys in order to find prime attributes is an exponential process. But this is necessary if we need to verify if a relation is in 3NF. Checking if a relation is in BCNF is computationally easier, since we need only to verify that all the determinants of the FDs of a cover are superkeys. And this can be done by computing the closures of the determinants.

Comment: "A relation is in third normal form when for all the FDs X -> Y of a cover" The closure, not a cover. Eg from Alice: "An fd schema (U, S) is in third normal form (3NF) if whenever X→A is a nontrivial fd implied by S, then either X is a superkey or A is a key attribute".